# Using output of MD5 of the key to decode stream using Base64 in java

Tags: base64, md5

for one of my tasks i am supposed to create MD5 hash of the key provided and use the hash output of MD5 as a key to Base64 decoding.

My question is:
1. Is it possible to decode a string in Base64 using a private key?
So far this is what i have done.

```
String key = MD5.getMD5("K3b2mTr3g0s1_B-m");//MD5.getMD5(key) will return MD5 hash of key passed
    byte[] raw = key.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        if (inputString != null) {
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            encryptedString = encoder.encode(encrypted);
            System.out.print("encrypted string :" + encryptedString);
        }
```

For the above implementation i am getting an exception: Invalid key foundjava.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

Answer (score 0):

The output of MD5 consists of 16 bytes.
An AES key consists of 16, 24 or 32 bytes.
Thus it is technically possible to use the output of MD5 as AES key.

Your problem is probably that the length of byte[] raw is not 16.
Indeed, MD5 operates on bytes, but in your implementation, the input and output are Strings. Also, the output of getBytes() is not well-defined (platform dependent).

Thus I suggest:

- verify the length of bytes[] raw,
- adapt your code for getMD5 to have bytes[] as input and output,
- do not use getBytes(), convert with an explicit encoding instead.